# Передать данные из формы в google charts

Tags: javascript, form, google-chart

Не работает диаграмма при передаче данных из формы, пожалуйста, подскажите в чем ошибка. Форму заполняю, но диаграмма не строится.

Код:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Form-->
    Mushrooms: <input id="mushrooms">
    <button id="drawChart">build</button>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        var mushrooms = getElementById(mushrooms).value;
        data.addRows([
          ['Mushrooms', mushrooms],
          ['Onions', 1],
          ['Olives', 1],
          ['Zucchini', 1],
          ['Pepperoni', 2]
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Код нужно добавлять в качестве сниппета, а не ссылкой.

Answer (score 1):

```js
    document.getElementById('drawChart').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        var mushrooms = document.getElementById('mushrooms').value;
        data.addRows([
          ['Mushrooms', parseInt(mushrooms)],
          ['Onions', 1],
          ['Olives', 1],
          ['Zucchini', 1],
          ['Pepperoni', 2]
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    });
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Form-->
    Mushrooms: <input id="mushrooms">
    <button id="drawChart">build</button>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Получение значения в js делается так

```
var mushrooms = document.getElementById('mushrooms').value;
```

Плюс не было обработчика кнопки

Comment: а как прирепить код этого скрипта к самому html-файлу? Просто я в javascriptе не сильно разбираюсь...)

Comment: эмм.. все скопировать в Html файл, только первую часть занести в `<script></script>`